# Setting Path for Mocha with --config

Tags: node.js, shell, path, mocha.js, nodemon

Mocha does not find the path to .mocharc.js file with the config.

The file is located at: app/test/.mocharc.js

I have tried setting relative as well as full paths and it always throws an error. Used quotation marks, double quotations, escaped quotations... Still I get the same error.

In package.json:

```
"scripts":{
    test": "nodemon --exec \"mocha --config \"./test/.mocharc.js\""
},
```

Command line Error log:

```
throw new Error(`failed to parse ${filepath}: ${err}`);
^
Error: failed to parse ./test/.mocharc.js: Error: Cannot find module './test/.mocharc.js'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `test` script command is in incorrect format (unnecessary double quote).

```
"scripts":{
    test": "nodemon --exec \"mocha --config ./test/.mocharc.js\""
},
```

You want to run `mocha --config ./test/.mocharc.js`.

And to wrap that into `nodemon`, you do:

```
nodemon --exec \"<command here>\"
```

Replace `<command here>` with your command like so.

```
nodemon --exec \"mocha --config ./test/.mocharc.js\"
```

Comment: I already tried with as you propose but I still get the same error

Comment: What command did you run to get that error? Does running `mocha --config ./test/.mocharc.js` work?